# Cocos2d-x turn based RPG game: run characters' attack animation in sequence

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am building a turn-based RPG game with Cocos2d-x 3.3final. I have four sprites, say sprite1, sprite2, sprite3 and sprite4. Each has an associated attack animation(class type Animate*), say sprite1attack, sprite2attack, sprite3attack, sprite4attack.

During the battle, every turn the attack order of these characters changes according to user's operation. In my code, I would like to have a menu callback function that could run the four character's attack animation in sequence when the user clicks its associated button:

```
void onStart(){

}
```

If I coded it like:

```
void onStart(){
    sprite1->runAction(sprite1attack);
    sprite2->runAction(sprite2attack);
    sprite3->runAction(sprite3attack);
    sprite4->runAction(sprite4attack);
}
```

The four animations would run all together.

Are there any good design pattern that can run the sprites' animation in any user wanted sequence?
It's OK to add variables, like `vector<int> attackOrder`.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to put Some `Action`s ( from TargetedAction) in sequence, you will need to use `TargetedAction`.

For example in your case you need something like this:

```
auto sequnecedAction = Sequence::create(
TargetedAction::create(sprite1,sprite1attackAnimation), 
TargetedAction::create(sprite2,sprite2attackAnimation), nullptr);

sprite1->runAction(sequnecedAction);
```